# get record count and join to another entity in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have two table:

1 : Role

2 : UserRoles

Consider the following command:

In SQL:

```
SELECT     RoleID, RoleName,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(UserID) AS UserCount
                            FROM          dbo.UserRoles AS UR
                            WHERE      (RoleID = R.RoleID)) AS UserCount
FROM         dbo.Roles AS R
```

What is the same script in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a LINQ to Entities query, for example:

```
var q = from role in context.Roles
  select new {
    role.RoleID,
    role.RoleName,
    UserCount = role.UserRoles.Count()
  };
```